# Case to extract multiple columns

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am wondering if there is something like Case where i can wok in SQL for getting multiple columns using 1 case expression in SQL Server 2005.  I am a rookie in SQL. Hope it is not too easy and i missed it. Thank you in advance!!

```
Select RD.RepDailyInfoID, RD.TypeofDayID
Case WHEN RD.TypeofDayID = 1
THEN 
    isnull(cast(S.AmountSold as numeric(10,2)), 0) as AmountSold,
    isnull(cast(S.S_AmountCollected as numeric(10,2)), 0) as AmountCollected,
    S.S_PaymentMethod as PaymentMethod

When RD.TypeofDayID = 9
THEN
    isnull(cast(U.AmountUpgraded as numeric(10,2)), 0) as AmountUpgraded,
    isnull(cast(U.U_UpgradedCollected as numeric(10,2)), 0) + isnull(cast(U.RenewalCollected as numeric(10,2)), 0) as AmountCollected,
    U.U_PaymentMethod as PaymentMethod
END
from RepDailyInfo RD
left outer join SellingInfo S on S.RepDailyInfoID = RD.RepDailyInfoID
left outer join UpgradingInfo U on U.RepDailyInfoID = RD.RepDailyInfoID
where RepID = @RepID
```

Comment: just copy+paste your case logic to each column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have multiple fields in the THEN part of a case statement.  You can just use the same logic to build multiple case statements:

```
Case WHEN RD.TypeofDayID = 1 THEN isnull(cast(S.AmountSold as numeric(10,2)), 0) END as AmountSold,
Case WHEN RD.TypeofDayID = 1 THEN isnull(cast(S.S_AmountCollected as numeric(10,2)), 0) END as AmountCollected
```

and etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is not tested but should get you started.  You have to have a case for each field.

```
    select  RD.RepDailyInfoID, RD.TypeofDayID
    , AmountSold = case when RD.TypeofDayID = 1 THEN  isnull(cast(S.AmountSold as numeric(10,2)), 0) else 0 end
    , AmountUpgraded = case when RD.TypeofDatID = 9 THEN isnull(cast(U.AmountUpgraded as numeric(10,2)), 0) else 0 end
    , AmountCollected = case when RD.TypeofDayID = 1 then isnull(cast(S.S_AmountCollected as numeric(10,2)), 0) else
                when RD.TypeofDayID = 9 then isnull(cast(U.U_UpgradedCollected as numeric(10,2)), 0) + isnull(cast(U.RenewalCollected as numeric(10,2)), 0) end
    , PaymentMethod = case when RD.TypeofDayID = 1 then S.S_PaymentMethod else
                when RD.TypeofDayID = 9 then U.U_PaymentMethod end
from RepDailyInfo RD
left outer join SellingInfo S on S.RepDailyInfoID = RD.RepDailyInfoID
left outer join UpgradingInfo U on U.RepDailyInfoID = RD.RepDailyInfoID
where RepID = @RepID
```

Answer (score 1):

Case does in fact exist. It's documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

I think your formatting may be a bit off, though. Try:

```
SELECT RD.RepDailyInfoID, AmountSold = 
  CASE RD.TypeofDayID
    WHEN '1' THEN isnull(cast(S.AmountSold as numeric(10,2)), 0)
  END
FROM RepDailyInfo RD
left outer join SellingInfo S on S.RepDailyInfoID = RD.RepDailyInfoID
left outer join UpgradingInfo U on U.RepDailyInfoID = RD.RepDailyInfoID
WHERE RepID = @RepID
```

I haven't tested it, but that's just my take on the formatting from a quick look at the documentation.

Good luck!

EDIT: Looks like Lance Ninja'd me. His code is more complete, but confirms (in part) what I'd thought was the case.